# How to reduce the TensorFlow Lite binary size with only the operators needed

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

The TensorFlow Lite binary size is about 900KB, and is still large for me. I want to know how to reduce the size with only the operators needed for supporting the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Tensorflow Lite

If you are using Tensorflow Lite, [the only solution I have found](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/g3doc/apis.md#customizing-the-kernel-library) is to work at level of `Interpreter` and customize the Kernel Library (`OpResolver`). I don't think there is an automatic way of doing this, and [the available only example (here the header)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/tools/gen_op_registration.h) is not so easy to understand IMHO. I think that more improvements on this topic will be included in the next releases. Also, **I'm not sure this will reduce the size of the final library**. In the API notes this approach is considered equivalent to the **selective registration**, that is explained in the next part of the answer for Tensorflow Mobile.

#### Tensorflow Mobile

As an answer to the question "How can I enable only the ops used by my model", the answer is in [Tensorflow Mobile Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/optimizing) (at the subsection Binary Size).

The usual size for Tensorflow Mobile seems to be 12MB, but it is possible to reduce it by including only the model required ops. Obviously this requires to build Tensorflow Lite as a Framework using Bazel.

You can create an header of required ops (`ops_to_register.h`) using the tool `print_selective_registration_header.py`, that is available [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d34b523f8f6af1b44626879729c7c33bfde4170e/tensorflow/python/tools/print_selective_registration_header_test.py). The generated header should be placed in the root of the Tensorflow source directory.
You are now ready to compile the library, passing the `SELECTIVE_REGISTRATION` definition to the compiler (building with Bazel, you should add the option: `--copts=”-DSELECTIVE_REGISTRATION”`).

I think this procedure will give the library with minimal ops inside. Some other compiler optimization flags may help you with the size (sometimes penalizing performance).

#### Compile options

I actually don't know how you are compiling your code (static lib or dynamic lib), which are your needs in terms of performance, and which are the default options in Tensorflow bazelfile, but you may try:

- to reduce the optimization to `-O1` or `-Os` (sometimes helps with the binary size, and I think the default for Tensorflow is `-O2` for the framework and `-O3` for the single kernels, I don't know for the lite version though).
- use the flags `-fdata-section` and `--gc-sections`: quoting `gcc` documentation: "[`-fdata-sections`] Together with a linker garbage collection (linker `--gc-sections` option) these options may lead to smaller statically-linked executables (after stripping)." (It seems that at least `--gc-sections` is used in [linker options for Raspberry Pi](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7558b085afd4ba8ffb5d9ceab0616cc4ba0649b1/tensorflow/contrib/lite/rpi_makefile.inc))
- `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden` should impact on performance of inline functions, but decreases the size of the export table of the shared object. This option *may* break the library. Some explanations can be read [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fvisibility-inlines-hidden).
- Even more dangerous is `-fvisibility=hidden`. Look at it [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fvisibility).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is for reducing the TensorFlow Mobile binary size, not the TensorFlow Lite.

Comment: This answer is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Glad that it helped, and sorry for the initial mistake.